# Interactive Switch Statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Im trying to make a switch statement, where the user is asked for a letter. Depending on the input. The user will get the color code number for the electronic color code chart. If the color is not in the electronic color code chart, the output will be "unknown color". I am having issues when the user inputs "b". How do i get the switch statement to output only brown, blue, or black. I can not use any if, else statements. */

```
#include <stdlib.h>         // Directive for Pause
#include <iostream>         // Directive for Input / Output
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char first_letter;
    char second_letter;
    char third_letter ;
    char electronic_color_code;

    cout << "Electronic Color Code" << endl << endl;

    cout << "To find out the digit of a particular color code," << endl <<
    "enter a letter: " ;
    cin >> electronic_color_code;
    cout << endl;

    switch (electronic_color_code)
    {
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            cout << "Red stands for digit 2.";
            break;

        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            cout << "Orange stands for digit 3.";
            break;

        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            cout << "Yellow stands for digit 4.";
            break;

        case 'v':
        case 'V':
            cout << "Violet stands for digit 7.";
            break;

        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            cout << "White stands for digit 9.";
            break;

        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            cout << "Enter a second letter: ";
            cin >> second_letter;
            cout << endl;
        case 'brows':
        case 'BROWS':
            cout << "Brown stands for digit 1.";
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case 'lue':
        case 'LUE':
            cout << "Enter a third letter: ";
            cin >> third_letter;
            cout << endl;
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            cout << "Black stands for digit 0.";
            cout << endl;
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            cout << "Blue stands for digit 6.";
            break;

        case 'g':
        case 'G':
            cout << "Enter the second and third letter" << endl;
            cin >> second_letter >> third_letter ;
        case 'rayd':
        case 'RAYD':
            cout << "Grey stands for the digit 8.";
        case 0:
        case 'reen':
        case 'REEN':
            cout << "Green stands for the digit 5." ;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Unknown Color";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    system ("Pause");        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'reen'` and the like are multicharacter literals that have an implementation-defined value.

Comment: Without if-elses (and I presume the ternary conditional operator) and having to get more than one letter, I think you'd have to do some kind of hash (`std::hash`) on the string you get, or actually put whole other switches in the cases where you need more letters.

Comment: All my case: statements have to be in a single switch statement.

Comment: WTB a `break` statement.

Comment: Once i put a break, the program will skip all other cases and output the last case value before the break. I have tried.

Comment: as a clever hack, you could try a variation on duff's device.  It's considered an antipattern though.

Comment: @RobertMason, How would that work? Maybe some crazy mathematical operation sequence planning to produce the correct final values :p

Comment: @SergioHernándezSaldaña: Just use a second switch inside your main switch if you hit 'b'?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @GuySirton, A single switch statement. Presumably homework or something like it where such restrictions are imposed.

Comment: @chris: Just store each read character in one byte single 64 bit unsigned integer, and then do your switch on that value, probably using macros to make the constants readable.  Works for colors less than 8 chars long :P

Comment: If this is homework, it's either the most nonsensical assignment I've seen yet or something has been misinterpreted. `iostream` will never return a multicharacter literal value.

Comment: this is the most wasteful program..

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have misinterpreted the assignment.

how can you think about taking a single character input and based on that you will choose colour!!!!

if user input is 'b' than there is no way to decide whether the color is black or brown. You need to take whole word as user input. for example you need to take input "XXXX" than string match it with "black" or "brown".